# plot data with 3 loops in python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, plot, nested

I have a dataframe df below: showing the number of kilometers done per day per type of people by type of car.

```
People      Car         dmy         value(km)
A         Renault    14-05-2016     500
B         Peugeot    14-05-2016     1000
A         Citroen    14-05-2016     400
A         Renault    15-05-2016     24
B         Peugeot    15-05-2016     247
A         Renault    15-05-2016     369
A         Citroen    23-05-2016     692
A         Citroen    28-05-2016     284
```

I have 20k lines over 1 year

This is what I have done:

```
 yy = (df["Car"] == 'Renault') & (df["People"] == 4) & (df["dmy"] == 15-05-2016)
```

I want to be able to iterate over these 3 elements in a fonction.

How can I create a triple loop to automatize this command?

```
Def my plot(df, Car, People, dmy)
    for i in car
        return i
    for j in People
       return j
for k in dmy
    return k
value = (df["Car"] == 'Renault') & (df["People"] == 4) & (df["dmy"] == 15-05-2016).yy['value', 'dmy']].groupby('dmy').aggregate(np.mean)
```

So that I can plot easily each graph for each value of i, j and k? Each plot should show the aggregated value of 'value', 'dmy' for each iteration of i, j and k.

The output must be a plot, where I call my fonction df (Car,People, dmy)

Thank you!

Comment: Your expected output is not very clear but wouldn't df.groupby(['People', 'Car', 'dmy']).mean() do the same?

Comment: + Not clear what type of graph you are looking for